# Template of the site?

Tags: python, html, css, static

I downloaded a free html template for training, the problem is as follows:

1. Trying to open the index page through python manage.py runserver, for some reason I get plain text without styles, etc. (Photo-1)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNzCY.png)
2. But if I open the same file, in the same folder, with a simple double click, then all the styles open, I don't understand. Why so, and help solve the problem. (Photo-2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YT3v.jpg)

If so, I can post the code. PLEASE JUST HELP!!!

I've tried everything

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Free Finance Website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--slider-->
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">    
  <div class="wrap"> 
    <div class="header-top">
         <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="index.html">Finance</a></h1>
         </div>
         <div class="menu">
            <div class="cssmenu">
                <ul>
                   <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="about.html"><span>About us</span></a></li>
                   <li><a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
                   <li class="has-sub"><a href="services.html"><span>Services</span></a></li>
                   <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                 </ul>
              </div>
          </div>    
          <div class="clear"></div> 
       </div>
   </div>   
</div>
      <!------ Slider ------------>
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/banner3.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/banner4.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img src="images/banner5.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!------End Slider ------------>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content-top">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="section group">
                <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                    <div class="thumb-pad2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h4>
                            <figure><img src="images/pic.jpg" alt=""><em class="sp1"></em></figure>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-default btn1">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                    <div class="thumb-pad2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                           <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h4>
                            <figure><img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt=""><em class="sp1"></em></figure>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-default btn1">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
                    <div class="thumb-pad2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h4>
                            <figure><img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt=""><em class="sp1"></em></figure>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-default btn1">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div> 
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-middle">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="section group group1">
                    <div class="section group grid2">
                            <div class="listview_1_of_2 images_1_of_2">
                                <div class="listimg listimg_2_of_1">
                                      <img src="images/chart.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="text list_2_of_1">
                                    <h3><span>Consectetur</span>  adipisicing elit</h3>
                                    <h4>Sed ut perspiciatis undeaccusantium .</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et dolore.</p>
                                    <div class="button"><span><a href="blog.html">LEARN MORE</a></span></div>
                               </div>
                           </div>           
                            <div class="listview_1_of_2 images_1_of_2">
                                <div class="listimg listimg_2_of_1">
                                      <img src="images/hand.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="text list_2_of_1">
                                      <h3><span>Consectetur</span>  adipisicing elit</h3>
                                      <h4>Sed ut perspiciatis undeaccusantium .</h4>
                                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et dolore.</p>
                                      <div class="button"><span><a href="blog.html">LEARN MORE</a></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div> 
                        </div>
                                <div class="section group grid2">
                                    <div class="listview_1_of_2 images_1_of_2">
                                        <div class="listimg listimg_2_of_1">
                                              <img src="images/bulb.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text list_2_of_1 ">
                                            <h3><span>Consectetur</span>  adipisicing elit</h3>
                                            <h4>Sed ut perspiciatis undeaccusantium .</h4>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et dolore.</p>
                                            <div class="button"><span><a href="blog.html">LEARN MORE</a></span></div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>           
                                    <div class="listview_1_of_2 images_1_of_2">
                                        <div class="listimg listimg_2_of_1">
                                              <img src="images/date.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text list_2_of_1">
                                              <h3><span>Consectetur</span>  adipisicing elit</h3>
                                              <h4>Sed ut perspiciatis undeaccusantium .</h4>
                                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ut labore et dolore.</p>
                                              <div class="button"><span><a href="blog.html">LEARN MORE</a></span></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div> 
                            </div>
                    </div>
          </div>
        <div class="content-bottom">
            <div class="map">
                <iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Lighthouse+Point,+FL,+United+States&amp;aq=4&amp;oq=light&amp;sll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;sspn=0.04941,0.104628&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Lighthouse+Point,+Broward,+Florida,+United+States&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Lighthouse+Point,+FL,+United+States&amp;aq=4&amp;oq=light&amp;sll=26.275636,-80.087265&amp;sspn=0.04941,0.104628&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Lighthouse+Point,+Broward,+Florida,+United+States&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.275636,-80.087265" style="color:#666;text-align:left;font-size:12px"></a></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="wrap">
        <div class="footer-top">
                <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>INFORMATION</h3>
                    <ul class="first">
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Legal Notice</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
                    <ul class="first">
                        <li><a href="#">New products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">top sellers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                    <h3>My ACCOUNT</h3>
                    <ul class="first">
                        <li><a href="#">Your Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Personal info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4 footer-lastgrid">
                    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
                    <ul class="last">
                            <li><span>+91-123-456789</span></li>
                            <li><span>+00-123-000000</span></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p>Design by <a href="http://w3layouts.com">W3layouts</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the text of the html?

Comment: yep. one second, pls

Comment: hi, could you check your console for errors? that might indicate the issue